# MS ACCESS FindRecord updates data

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a small DB with a table of employees and their IDs (key fields). I created a form for this table and I'm trying to add a button that will allow the user to check whether a certain ID already exists in the DB before he saves the record.
I'm trying to use FindRecord, but it seems to try and update the field before searching it. This way I get an error that I'm trying to add an new record with existing key field.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Shaked

Comment: The user can add new employee using the form. I want to allow him that upon entering the ID (which is defined by 9-digit input mask) he'll be able to click the "Check if ID already exists" button and get the information

Answer (score 0):

You can create a combo box on your form to look up existing employee IDs. The wizard will guide you through creating the combo. The user can then type in a number or name and if it exits, the record will be shown. You can use the Not In List event to run code if the number is not found. This is usually quite nice for your users, because the autocomplete will "guess" the number.

[image: find using combo]